# Cloud9 showing blank white screen after "Loading Your Workspace" screen

Tags: cloud9-ide, beagleboneblack

I've been doing development on the Beaglebone Black using the Cloud9 IDE for over a year now. It always worked for me until today when suddenly it started showing a blank white screen after the "Loading Your Workspace" screen. The Cloud9 IDE works fine when working directly in the BBB but not when I remotely access it from 192.168.7.2:3000.

I've tried the following to troubleshoot:
- Cleared all browser data, cookies, etc.
- Tried on two separate BBB with clean re-installation of Debian. This image always worked fine for me in the past. Both BBB show the same result.
- Tried the BBB on two separate computers, one Win7 and the other Win8.
- Tried on both Chrome and IE.

Everything I tried showed the same result. It really has me baffled! Can anyone offer some words of wisdom?

My only guess is that some client side script in the Cloud9 IDE is making a call to a server which is down at the moment. But, my understanding is that the Cloud9 IDE is completely contained in the BBB and makes no external calls from the client.

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console? Recently chrome started throwing errors when doing `Document.prototype.onreadystatechange = null;`

Comment: The console reports an error 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation' from the default.js script. This is a Cloud9 IDE file. It seems to be starting plugins when the error occurs. I haven't been able to narrow it down more than this yet.

Comment: For what it's worth, this just started happening to me too.  Chrome Canary exhibits the same behavior.  Safari works fine.

Comment: RESOLVED - I upgraded to the latest Debian image from Beaglebone.org and remote Cloud9 works fine. I'm using the Debian 7.8 build from 2015-03-01.